# Load balancer apache what's wrong

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, virtualhost

I' trying to make a load balancing using apache but when I got to my (Local)host 'load'
got **Not found**

I've been load those mods

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
```

this is my vhost:

```
ServerName load

ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Proxy balancer://wwwCluster>
    BalancerMember http://localhost:1001 loadfactor=1
    BalancerMember http://localhost:1002 loadfactor=5
    BalancerMember http://localhost:1003 loadfactor=3

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from none
    Allow from all

    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /balancer balander://wwwCluster
```

the balancer manager work pretty good
    
        SetHandler balancer-manager
        Allow from all

Comment: have you tried `http://load` ??

Comment: when I say That I got "not found" that why I've gone to http://load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a typo in your configuration, hence the 500 error when you go to load

`ProxyPass /balancer balander://wwwCluster`

Change it to **balancer**, instead of balander

Comment: Well spotted!!!